# How to get URI of a blob in a google cloud storage (Python)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

If I have a Blob object how can I get the URI (gs://...)?

The documentation says I can use self_link property to get the URI, but it returns the https URL instead (https://googleapis.com...) 
I am using python client library for cloud storage.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not sharing with us how exactly are you trying to achieve this I did a quick script in [Python](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) to get this info

There is no specific method in blob to get the URI as `gs://` in Python but you can try to script this by using the `path_helper`

```
def get_blob_URI():
    """Prints out a bucket's labels."""
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = 'YOUR_BUCKET'
    blob_name = 'YOUR_OBJECT_NAME'
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    link = blob.path_helper(bucket_name, blob_name)
    pprint.pprint('gs://' + link)
```

If you want to use the `gsutil` tool you can also get all the `gs://` Uris of a bucket using the command `gsutil ls gs://bucket`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought there might be a built-in method I was unaware of.

Comment: This method adds an odd '/o/' in between the bucket name and the blob name. It also replaces '/' with %.

Comment: Editing my prior comment to say that I'm seeing an undocumented `Blob.name` property which contains the original path used to construct the Blob object. So `"gs://" + blob.bucket.name + "/" + blob.name` should give something closer to what's wanted here

Comment: I get an "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Bucket' and 'str'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can take the `blob.id` and chop off the generation from the end of it:

```py
def get_blob_uri(blob):
    return 'gs://' + blob.id[:-(len(str(blob.generation)) + 1)]
```

Relevant docs:

- [blob.id](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_id)
- [blob.generation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_generation)